# Date calculations in power shell

Tags: powershell, date, while-loop

I wrote a piece of code where I need 10 dates that are 110 hours apart but I am missing something. Can you please advise?

```
$Date = [DateTime] "10/17/2020 01:11 AM"
$Int = 10
Do { $Date.AddHours(110); $Int-- } While ($Int -ge 1)
```

Output:

```
Wednesday, October 21, 2020 3:11:00 PM
Wednesday, October 21, 2020 3:11:00 PM
Wednesday, October 21, 2020 3:11:00 PM
Wednesday, October 21, 2020 3:11:00 PM
Wednesday, October 21, 2020 3:11:00 PM
Wednesday, October 21, 2020 3:11:00 PM
Wednesday, October 21, 2020 3:11:00 PM
Wednesday, October 21, 2020 3:11:00 PM
Wednesday, October 21, 2020 3:11:00 PM
Wednesday, October 21, 2020 3:11:00 PM
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DateTime` in .NET is implemented as an *immutable* type - its value cannot be modified once created.

So the `Add()` method returns a new `DateTime` object reflecting the time difference, but the existing object assign to `$Date` still has the same value.

You'll need to overwrite `$Date` with the new value on each iteration:

```
Do { $Date = $Date.AddHours(110); $Date; $Int-- } While ($Int -ge 1)
```